# Crash in ParseFacebookUtils on Android after upgrading Facebook Unity SDK from 4.3.6 to 5.0.4

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-unity-sdk

After upgrading the Facebook Unity SDK from 4.3.6 to the 5.0.4 beta our game is crashing on Android during login in ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync() with a null reference exception.

Our game uses Parse for user save persistence for cross-platform play. The only Parse login process we are using is via Facebook, through the method ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync().

Here's the relevant part of the stack:

```
I/Unity   (17210): NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I/Unity   (17210):   at Parse.ParseUser.LogInWithAsync (System.String authType, IDictionary`2 data,
CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (17210):   at Parse.ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync (System.String facebookId, System.String
accessToken, DateTime expiration, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   (17210):   at Parse.ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync (System.String facebookId, System.String
accessToken, DateTime expiration) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm certain that the Facebook ID and access token provided to ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync() are correct. Interestingly, this Parse call does not crash in the Editor when using 5.0.4.

We are on the latest version of the Parse SDK for Unity - 1.2.14 as of this writing.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Comment: New info - this may be OS / device specific. The crash is occurring on a Samsung Galaxy S4 that was just updated to the latest Android OS available to it - 4.4.2. On a Kindle Fire HDX, this crash does not occur.

Comment: Also does not crash on a Nexus 7 (1st gen) that is also running 4.4.2. Note that the non-crashing Kindle Fire HDX and Nexus 7 do not have the Facebook app installed, if that matters. The Galaxy S4 does have it installed.